# How to have rendered node html in a preprocess function

Tags: nodes, webforms, theming

I need to pre-fill a webform hidden field with the nid of a node and display the node formatted in 'preview' mode.

I formatted the URL like

```
  www.example.com/urlwebform?nid=56
```

and I built a preprocess like this one

```
function custom_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) {
  switch ($hook) {
    case 'webform_form':
        if( isset($_REQUEST['nid']) ){
            $vars['form']['submitted']['nid_field']['#value'] = $_REQUEST['nid'];
            $vars['form']['submitted']['pacchetto_nid']['#suffix'] = 'FORMATTED NODE HTML'
        } 
        break;
  }
}
```

Now, how can I retrive the formatted HTML node in preview mode to display it?

Comment: is Drupal 7 right?

Comment: Based on the info provided, I think you could do this in the UI just using Tokens and changing the View mode to show or hide whatever field this is.

Comment: Yes it's Drupal 7. 
@heart.cooks.mind Con you provide an example cose